# Deprecated constructor for BigDecimal.setScale(int, int) and RoundingMode enums

Tags: java, enums, deprecated, bigdecimal, deprecation-warning

I'm trying to specify the precision of a BigDecimal value with the following: `new BigDecimal(12.99).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN`. However, the compiler is telling me that `setScale(int, int)` is deprecated.

When I've tried to use the RoundingMode enums, it's telling me that the enum may not have been initialised. How do I correctly use the enums to instantiate the BigDecimals with `setScale(int, RoundingMode)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Show a runnable example with code that I can copy into an editor to reproduce your issue.

Comment: If you want to create a BigDecimal with the value 12.99, just use `BigDecimal.valueOf(1299, 2)`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou. I meant the code that is causing the "not initialized" issue. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I wasn't talking to you ;) I agree with what you said. My comment was simply to let the OP know of another way to initialise a BigDecimal (which also guarantees no rounding).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the docs, `setScale(int, int)`, has not been recommended since [Java 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20int)), when enums were first introduced:

> The new `setScale(int, RoundingMode)` method should be used in preference to this legacy method.

It was finally deprecated in [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-int-).

You should call [`setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) instead. It makes error checking much simpler, since you can't pass in an undefined `enum`, but you can certainly pass in an integer mode which is undefined.

Answer (score 9):

You should not "instantiate" an enum but use its constants. Have you tried:

```
new BigDecimal(12.99).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Note that you could also use the string constructor:

```
new BigDecimal("12.99");
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give good guidance regarding rounding modes - but to a certain degree they miss another crucial point. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)):

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable.

The whole point is: when you pass a **double** value, then **floating point** semantics kick in.

In other words: you intend to use a special, expensive "overhead" object to deal with arbitrary floating point numbers. But you start the thing by basing it on a value that is restricted to Java double semantics.

Go for `new BigDecimal("12.99")` instead, or `new BigDecimal(1299, 2)`.

Comment: Good info, but technically not what OP is asking about. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks for your input. I reworded my answer a bit to make it more clear why it is of real help given the code example provided by the OP.